# Varnish 3.0 Guru Meditation with FetchError TestGunzip error at the very end

Tags: varnish

I'm getting intermittent guru meditations in varnish (as in I fire 50 requests off and 3 come back bad).  In varnishlog it says

```
   15 VCL_return   c hash
   15 HitPass      c 1394372109
   15 VCL_call     c pass pass
   15 Backend      c 17 default default
   15 TTL          c 1394372164 RFC 0 -1 -1 1384590297 0 1384590291 0 0
   15 VCL_call     c fetch
   15 TTL          c 1394372164 VCL 120 -1 -1 1384590297 -0
   15 VCL_return   c hit_for_pass
   15 ObjProtocol  c HTTP/1.1
   15 ObjResponse  c OK
   15 ObjHeader    c Date: Sat, 16 Nov 2013 08:24:51 GMT
   15 ObjHeader    c Server: Apache
   15 ObjHeader    c Accept-Ranges: bytes
   15 ObjHeader    c Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
   15 ObjHeader    c Vary: Accept-Encoding
   15 ObjHeader    c X-Mod-Pagespeed: 1.5.27.2-2912
   15 ObjHeader    c Content-Encoding: gzip
   15 ObjHeader    c Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   15 Gzip         c u F - 3755 13624 80 0 0
   15 FetchError   c TestGunzip error at the very end
   15 VCL_call     c error deliver
   15 VCL_call     c deliver deliver
   15 TxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
   15 TxStatus     c 503
   15 TxResponse   c Service Unavailable
```

You can see the `15 FetchError   c TestGunzip error at the very end` which is the problem. I'm not sure how to interpret the line above `Gzip         c u F - 3755 13624 80 0 0` and I can't see why this is a problem.  The site did not have any reported problem loading pages before we put varnish in front.

In an assumption that varnish is just being more strict about gzip than the browsers are, I attempted to turn off the gzip handling, so I set `http_gzip_support` to off in `/etc/defaults/varnish`:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m \
             -p http_gzip_support=off"
```

This has failed to make any difference.  I've now run out of ideas, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is the fix

```
if (beresp.status == 301 || beresp.status == 302) {
  if (beresp.http.Content-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
    if (beresp.http.Content-Length == "0") {
      unset beresp.http.Content-Encoding;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Some more explanation would be appreciated in this answer.

Comment: The Varnish author explained it here: https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/ticket/1320

Answer (score 0):

```
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
      # If the browser supports it, we'll use gzip.
      #set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
      unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    }
    else if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
      # Next, try deflate if it is supported.
      set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
    }
    else {
      # Unknown algorithm. Remove it and send unencoded.
      unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    }
}
```

I put the unset Accept-Encoding and when the response comes back from the backend it doesn't try to TestGunZip it. Thats what it seems like. This is my fix i have because i too have had the same issues.

Comment: This is a terrible idea since this way you are just disabling gzip compression for every request.